# How do I return a double?

Tags: c

5. Create a function called functionXYZ that returns a DOUBLE. This function should also accept a DOUBLE as input.
6. functionXYZ should take a DOUBLE as an input, times this value by 10, and then return the result.
7. In your MAIN method, test out your newly created function. Write some simple code that will use functionXYZ… In your MAIN, create a new DOUBLE variable and set it equal to 5.7. Pass this variable to your new function functionXYZ and save the returned value into a new DOUBLE variable. Print out this new variable that contains the returned value from functionXYZ Now you can verify that your function is working correctly.

---

So far, I have (*transferred from a comment and formatted*):

```
double functionXYZ (double data)
{
    return *10;
}

int main(void)
{
    double val = 5.7;
    double val = 2.4;
    double val = 9.5;
    double val = 3.7
    double result = functionXYZ (val);
    double result1 = functionXYZ (val1);
    double result2 = functionXYZ (val2);
    double result3 = functionXYZ (val3);
    printf("n/n Your total is: %if\n",result);
    printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result1);
    printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result2);
    printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result3);
    printf("n\Press ENTER to exit ");
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Post what you've tried so far. Be specific if you're getting errors so we can help you in a better way.

Comment: See thats the thing im not reallu sure where to start all i have is this

Comment: double functionXYZ (double data)
{
 
  return *10 ;
}

int main (void)
{

double val = 5.7;
double val = 2.4;
double val= 9.5 ;
double val= 3.7 

double result = functionXYZ (val);
double result1 = functionXYZ (val1);
double result2 = functionXYZ (val2);
double result3 = functionXYZ (val3);

printf("n/n Your total is: %if\n",result);
printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result1);
printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result2);
printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result3);

printf("n\Press ENTER to exit ");
return 0;

Comment: Edit that code into your question!  The question is … confusing.  `DOUBLE` is not a standard type in C (but `double` is), and `MAIN` is not a standard function (but `main()` is).  C is case-sensitive.  And maybe something similar with the other SHOUTED names and types.  Is that really 'function XYZ' so the name is three letters rather than 11?

Comment: I will refrain from jumping on the gang-downvote wagon. 3 is plenty. Your return type from a function is governed by the `type` of the function (e.g. `int foo (int a) {return a + a;}` returns an `int`, `double foo (int a) {return a + a;}` returns a double)

Comment: im guessing my code is wrong as its not letting me save it its telling me its correctly formatted

Comment: I've edited what you pasted into the answer and formatted it for you — as best I can.  You need to multiply `data * 10.0` in the return statement. You should be getting errors for two missing semicolons, for definining variable `val` four times, for not defining `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`.  The `n/n` should probably be `\n\n`; the occurrences of `\ n` should not have a space in between the two symbols.  Using `%if` is wrong; it tries to print an integer followed by the letter `f`; you probably want `%f` or `%.2f` or something similar.  `n\P` should probably be `\nP`.  You don't actually wait.

Comment: `return *10;` is where you have a problem, though the compiler should tell you.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you basically have it right, but you are not yet multiplying the argument value. So your function should be

```
double functionXYZ (double data)
{
    return data * 10;
}
```

The type *before the function name* determines its 'return type' (what type of variables can be expected to be returned by this function). In this case, it is `double`, so as long as you use the `return` keyword with a double value, you are correctly returning a double.

**Edit**

There are also a number of bugs in your `main()` function. To get this to compile correctly, you must do the following:

Make sure variables have unique names; You have `double val` several times. That means you are trying to declare to the compiler that there is a `double` variable called `val` more than once, which is an error.

Change the line(s) that look like this

```
printf(" Your total is: %if \ n " result1);
```

to

```
printf(" Your total is: %if \n ", result1);
```

Note adding the missing comma. Also removing the space between the \ and the n is not a compile bug but it is an obvious typo.

Make sure that every time you refer to a variable, it is one you have actually defined. So for example

```
double result2 = functionXYZ (val2);
```

calls your function with a variable called `val2`, except at no point in your code to you actually *define* `val2`.

Comment: That's the error in the function; there are a number of problems in `main` too.

Comment: Thank you so much my teacher doesn't explain properly and so is my code ?

Comment: No problem @Siya can you accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it please :)

Comment: Im still getting errors ive got like 12 errors now

Comment: What are the errors

Comment: Most of them are  (ntelliSense: identifier "val2" is undefined )

Comment: @Siya Edited...

Comment: Im new to this sadly i can yet move to a discussion

Comment: its still not complying im now confused at this point ive fixed the errors you told me thank you ben !:)

Comment: Thank you so much i was missing a semi colon the slightest thing :)